# How to access an Arrays value by the value of another array

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

```
$query = "select Code , count(ListID) as nums  from accesstable where Cust=" . $_SESSION ['Cust'] . " and App=" . $_SESSION ['App'] . " group by Code";
$result = mysql_query ( $query );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result )){       
    $Codes[] = $row['Code'];
    $Values[] = $row['nums'];
}
```

This is the structure of my code that I am trying to learn how to properly access... Here is my dilemma... I am trying to figure out how to explicitly find the associated count of nums dependent on the value of a Code.

**Let me explain in better detail where my issue is....**

Lets say the list of codes is

**Code     nums**
    1            624
    7            825
   571         450
    9            393
    2            739
    9            590

The above code does successfully allow me to separate those values strictly into keys and values but I cannot figure out how to grab the nums value if the code is = to a certain value... I have currently been trying to declare a variable above the entire snippet of code and then declare it within the while statement but cannot figure out how to get the value to bind properly.... I will repaste the above code with one of my many failures in the while statement to give a better idea.

**$Answer1 = 0;**

```
$query = "select Code , count(ListID) as nums  from accesstable where Cust=" . $_SESSION ['Cust'] . " and App=" . $_SESSION ['App'] . " group by Code";
$result = mysql_query ( $query );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result )){ 

$Codes[] = $row['Code'];
$Values[] = $row['nums'];

($Codes == 1){
    $Answer1 = // Right Here I want to Get the value 624 related to Code 1... Dont want to embarass myself with examples of what I have tried...
}
```

So how do I make a condition to output the value associated with a Code? I want to explicitly define these values as the list of codes can change with each customer... Luckily there are only a certain amount of codes so its not like I need to define too many of them... I just want to make sure I can get the nums value associated with a code and display it.

Hope I did a good job explaining this. :)

Comment: How can you have two different nums (ie. 393 and 590) for the same code (ie. 9)?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result )){       
    $Codes[] = $row['Code'];
    $Values[$row['Code']] = $row['nums'];
}
```

and, to access the value associated to a code:

```
$code = 1;
$value = $values[$code];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they would share the same array key, something like this would work-

```
if ($Codes[$key] == 1){
         $Answer1 = $Values[$key];
}
```